# Undefining constant inside macro after single use

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I would like to have macro which will undefine constant passed to it when called.
Something like this:

```
#define CONSTANT1 123

#define macro(const) \
#ifdef const \
const \
#undef const \
#else \
#error "constant already used once" \
#endif

int main(){
int a = macro(CONSTANT1); // a = 123
int b = macro(CONSTANT1); // <- preprocessor error "constant already used once"
return 0;
}
```

It is possible to archive this functionality with preprocessor?

Comment: consider `#undef CONSTANT1` after the first use

Comment: maybe use the `__COUNTER__`-macro as described here: https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/C-C-plus-plus/preprocessor/macros/predefined/__COUNTER__

Comment: @MortenJensen, it may work only if `macro` was the only user of *`__COUNTER__`*

Comment: Simply don't use the preprocessor in this manner. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: It will not even compile for many reasons https://godbolt.org/z/YGxWxajjW

Comment: @0___________ Yes of course, it was only example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to get it with standard C preprocessor but it is possible to do it with GCC/CLANG pragmas like `push_macro/pop_macro`:

```
// define a macro that will generate error on expansion
#define CONSTANT1 _Pragma("GCC error \"CONSTANT1 expanded more than once\"")

// save this macro and undefine it
#pragma push_macro("CONSTANT1")
#undef CONSTANT1

// let CONSTANT1 expand to 123, but replace with
// previous error-generation macro 
#define CONSTANT1 123 _Pragma("pop_macro(\"CONSTANT1\")") 


int a = CONSTANT1;
int b = CONSTANT1;
```

Compiling with `gcc`/`clang` produced:

```
prog.c:8:11: error: CONSTANT1 expanded more than once
    8 | int b = CONSTANT1;
```

Note that pragmas `push_macro`/`pop_macro` are quite portable and they are supported by GCC,CLANG,MSVS and Intel C Compiler.

A bit more portable version of failing `CONSTANT1` could be:

```
#define CONSTANT1 sizeof(struct {_Static_assert(0, "CONSTANT1 expanded more than once"); int x; })
```

It requires C11 compatible compiler.

Comment: Thank you, even if it's not possible with standard C preprocessor still this approach is helpful.